# Woher stammt die (regionale) Bedeutung "seltsam, komisch" für "glatt"?

Tags: etymology, dialect, colloquial, swabian, swiss-german

Unter den vielfältigen Bedeutungen für ***["glatt"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/glatt)*** kann ich eine, zumindest hier im süddeutsch-schwäbischen Raum gebräuchliche Bedeutung nicht finden.

Beispiel:

> Fritz findet seine Pantoffeln nicht wie üblich unter dem Bett, sondern neben dem Kelleraufgang. Darüber ist er sehr verwundert und ruft aus: *"Ha! Des isch glatt, wer hôt mir au die dô nagstellt?"*

Dieser Aufruf übersetzt sich etwa wie folgt: *"Ha! Das ist **seltsam/komisch/lustig**, wer hat sie mir dort hingelegt?"*

Nun frage ich mich, ob wir etwas zur Herkunft dieser Bedeutung wissen. Gibt es eine ähnliche Verwendung für *"glatt"* auch in anderen deutschsprachigen Regionen?

Nachtrag: Offenbar bedeutet *"glatt"* auch in der Schweiz *"lustig"* <sup>[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Diskussion%3aglatt), [Mundmische](http://mundmische.de/bedeutung/13336-glatt), [Alemannische Wikipedia](http://als.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glatt)</sup>

Comment: Interessant! Wo ich lebe, hat *glatt* auch eine zweite, wenn auch andere, Bedeutung: *"I bin glatt Erschter g'worden!"* (Ich bin wirklich/echt (erstaunlicherweise) Erster geworden!) - Bei näherem Überlegen: Das gibt's auch hochsprachlich: *"Das hat mich glatt umgehauen." - "Das hat mich glatt überfordert."*

Comment: @splattne: ich habe noch etwas über die Schweiz gefunden.

Comment: @splattne: Das "glatt" in "das hat mich glatt umgehauen" gehört zu einer anderen Wortart als das "glatt" in "das ist glatt". Dein "glatt" ist ein Modalpartikel. Das ist eine Wortart, die eigentlich nur in der deutschen Sprache breite Anwendung findet, aber z.B. im Englischen praktisch gar nicht vorkommt, welhalb man diese Wörter beim Übersetzen meist weglässt. Das "glatt" aus Takkats Beispiel ist hingegen ein ganz normales Adjektiv, gehört also zu einer Wortart, die, soweit mir bekannt ist, in jeder Sprache vorkommt und daher beim Übersetzen keine Probleme macht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quelle: http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemid=GG17674 DWB Deutsches Wörterbuch der Brüder Grimm:

> glatt, adj. herkunft und form. ahd. glat, clat 'glänzend', mhd. glat,
>   gelat 'glänzend, eben, schlüpfrig', mnl. glat, gelad 'schlüpfrig', nl.
>   glad 'schlüpfrig, eben', afries. gled 'schlüpfrig', ags. glæd und
>   mengl. glæd, glad, gled 'glänzend, fröhlich, angenehm', engl. glad
>   'froh, erheiternd, angenehm', as. gladmôd 'fröhlich', anord. glaðr
>   'blank, hell, froh', dän. und norw., schwed. glad, woneben dän., norw.
>   glat, schwed. glatt 'eben, schlüpfrig' als lehnwort aus dem nhd. (vgl.
>   Falk-Torp 1, 326).

Von glatt -> schlüpfrig -> komisch sehe ich einen Zusammenhang. Interessant auch der Verweis auf das engl. "glad, to be ~" (froh, fröhlich).

Comment: Vgl dies mit den IE Wurzeln zu *kalt, cold*, bzw. IE. "gelati" (Eis) und dann wirds dich *eiskalt erwischen*. Ist das nicht *cool*, voll *geil*? Gab aber noch eine andere Wurzel die mir zu *glatt* in diesem Sinne auffiel, aber ich stelle mich einfach zu *glatt* an und kann mir nix merken.

Answer (score 0):

Glatt is similar to:

> Dass haut mich doch glatt um!
>
> Das reisst mich doch [glatt] vom Hocker.

Glatt is similar to the word fishy in english. Fish is slippery as well.

Glatt is something happened without you noticing because somebody slipped your slippers somewhere without you noticing.

Smooth comes to mind from the english language. Smooth criminal. In German geschmeidig or aalglatt. Is a Person that is so smooth that you cannot catch him or pin him down.

Slipping through the cracks.

I think I'll stop slipping down the longwinded posting slope.

Comment: This exactly is the other meaning of *"glatt"* splattne mentioned in a comment above. :)

Comment: @DisplayName: The word "glatt" that you did use is from a different kind of word than the "glatt" in Takkats example. Takkats "glatt" is an adjective, that is part of almost every language. But you used a modal particle that is typically for german language and is hard to translate into other languages like english. Take this two sentences: "Das haut mich um." and "Das haut mich glatt um." and try to translate them into english.